# Matplotlib pyplot savefig output has different data to show

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I've got a loop for making a large number of charts by filtering a PANDAS dataframe:

```
def makeChart(name):    
    plt.clf()
    plt.cla()

    filename = "plots/" + name.replace(" ","_")
    series = df[df['name'] == name]
    series_wk = series[['name','start_date','num_nights']].groupby([pd.Grouper(key='start_date', freq='W')]).sum().reset_index()
    series_wk['period'] = series_wk.apply(checkperiod, axis=1)
    series_wk.set_index('start_date',inplace=True)
    series_wk.to_csv(filename + ".csv")

    ne = series_wk[series_wk['period'] == "Non-election"]
    e = series_wk[series_wk['period'] == "Election"]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
    ax.bar(ne.index, ne['num_nights'], color='b')
    ax.bar(e.index, e['num_nights'], color='r')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(50))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))
    ax.set_title(name)
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    fig.savefig(filename)
    plt.show()

makeChart("CARR Kim")
```

The output of plt.show() has the correct data, and [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH7eV.png)
However the saved file has incorrect data, and [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIgBt.png).
I'm new to using matplotlib, and really can't figure out why the actual data points would differ here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: ps - assume the function is properly indented, it broke when I pasted it in!

Comment: Would you mind providing your data file ?

Comment: Both are correct and incorrect somehow. Maybe you're more lucky in the first case to see those bars you want to see. The underlying problem is that bars are too small to be shown. Either use a larger `width` or set an `edgecolor` explicitely.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest setting an explicit width worked, thank you!